# Kafka connector exception ERROR Failed to send HTTP request to endpoint: http://localhost:8081/subjects/jdbc-source-accounts-value/versions

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I'm using Confluent Platform 3.3 as a Kafka connector , while starting the connector using the below command,

```
./bin/connect-standalone ./etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties ./etc/kafka-connect-jdbc/connect-jdbc-source.properties
```

getting the below error

```
ERROR Server died unexpectedly:  (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryMain:52)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata
[2017-10-30 13:49:56,178] ERROR Failed to send HTTP request to endpoint: http://localhost:8081/subjects/jdbc-source-accounts-value/versions 
(io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService:156)
```

The Zookeeper is running in kafka client 2181 port, and I tried to start schema by the below command

```
 ./bin/schema-registry-start ./etc/schema-registry/schema-registry.properties &
```

But it didn't show any error messages but the port 8081 didn't up.Please help me to sort this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Confluent Platform 3.3, I would recommend using [Confluent CLI](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-cli) since it's part of the download you've already got and makes life much simpler. Then you can easily check the status of the components.

```
confluent start
confluent status kafka
```

etc

Check out this vid here: https://vimeo.com/228505612

In terms of the issue you've got, I would check the log for Schema Registry. You can do that with Confluent CLI

```
confluent log schema-registry
```

Answer (score 3):

I also seen same issue while running the producer with Spring Cloud Stream. Replacing the localhost with actual IP address will help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone, l faced a similar issue. The solution that worked for me was to change localhost in my connector settings (in my schema.registry.url) and replace it with the ip address of of the container for/running schema registry and it worked. For example

l had set it up like below:

```
"value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081"
"key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081"
```

and l changed it to the following

```
"value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://172.19.0.4:8081",
 "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://172.19.0.4:8081"
```